# Possible ways to emulate \A and \z meta escapes (string anchors)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found that `\A` can be emulated with:

```regex
(?<!\s)^
```

and PCRE(2)/re2 `\z` (Python `\Z`) can be emulated with:

```regex
$(?!\s)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hrkS0H/1)

How else can `\A` and/or `\z` be emulated in JS?

Even [regular-expression.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az) has no mention of what I've presented.

Comment: Make it singleline instead of multiline and then use [`^|$`](https://regex101.com/r/I3TGRR/1)?

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh Sorry, I forgot about `/s`. It's relatively new to JS so I'd like to avoid it as well.

Comment: You can then get them from group 1 and group 2. [`(^)[\s\S]*($)`](https://regex101.com/r/XvsTQG/1). Group 1 contains `\A` and group 2 contains `\Z`

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh Very creative. I'd love it if you could post these solutions as answers. My inspiration for asking this question stems from my recent answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70608182/2191572

Comment: Are you silently saying you are using the `m` flag? If not, then `^`  and `$` already act like this by default in JS.

Comment: I'm considering turning this into a Wiki because even the best of my Google-ability keeps yielding results for `^` and `$`. I think many people don't know the existence of `\A` and `\z` so there's probably A LOT of faulty regex in the wild.

Comment: @trincot Good question. The more I think about it the more I realize I'm just soliciting any and all alternatives for `\A` and `\z`.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You are not making it clear. There is no `\A` and `\z` support in JS, because `^` and `$` do exactly that when `m` flag is not used. `^` matches string start and `$` matches the *very* end of string without multiline flag. Currently, the answer is just "use `^` and `$`".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was hoping to use this post as a catch-all for `\A` and `\z` emulation in JS and even incorporate it into the **Anchors** section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2191572. Using Google it is near impossible to find proper results for "JS regex start/end of string". Omitting the `m` flag and using `^` and `$` is one viable solution but if you need to match one of those anchors in the middle of the text then that method will not work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Additionally, if "There is no `\A` and `\z` support in JS, because `^` and `$` do exactly that when m flag is not used." is true then why do other flavors have `\A` and `\z` support?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70608182/2191572) inspired me to ask this generalized question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020821/3832970 is already answering what `\A`, `\Z` and `\z` does, and it is part of "What does this regex mean" post. Why shouldn't we close this question as a dupe of that post? All three main unambiguous anchors are explained concisely. Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70608182/2191572) deals with the problem of emulating `\A` when you need to use `^` with `m` flag.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sure, and I do not suggest to close [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70607585), but this one. Unless you precise the question to dwell on JavaScript only and state clearly you discuss the `\A` and `\z` equivalents in JS regex when `m` flag is used. Partially, [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515368/3832970) answers it, only the very start of string is not dealt with there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, my previous comment was irrelevant because I misread your comment. Anyways, I did not find your post via Google, Stack Overflow search, nor the existing [canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). I'd like to propose adding my post to the canonical under **Anchors** as a dedicated Javascript entry.

Comment: Please consider editing the post as I suggested in my comments, else, it sounds too broad and just as if you were looking for `^` and `$`. Which is not really that new and of much value. And their bahvior in JS can just be added to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908725/. Also, maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832215/3832970) is also explaining the `$` / `\z` part. Hm, if I add `\A` part there, it may be just what you want to get here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Those posts are language-specific and it's not Javascript. I'll consider editing per your comments when I have some time.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the lookarounds that you have used, you can try one of the following:

Disable the multiline modifier. InJavascript, by default, `^` matches `\A` and `$` matches `\z` and use:

```
^|$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ev3Eiy/1)**

or

you can capture them in groups as shown below:

```
(^)[\s\S]*($)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XvsTQG/1)**

---

- `(^)` - match the start of the first line and capture it in group 1
- `[\s\S]*` - greedily match 0+ occurences of any character(including newlines)
- `($)` - match the end of the last line and capture it in group 2

Comment: Can you provide a case where using `(^)[\s\S]*($)` would be useful? The regex is guaranteed to return a match, and it will always be the whole input, and the capture groups will always be two empty strings. I fail to see how that brings any benefit.

Comment: *"Single-line mode causes the engine to treat the multi-line input string as a single line. Thus, `^` would match the "very-start" and `$` would match the "very-end"*:  No, the `s` flag does not influence the behaviour of `^` nor `$`. This "very start and very end" behaviour is already the default in JS.

Comment: @trincot I was just thinking of possible ways in which we can match `\A` and `\z` apart from the lookarounds, You are correct about the default behavior in javascript. With or without the single-line modifier, [`^` behaves like `\A` and `$` behaves like `\z`](https://regex101.com/r/ev3Eiy/1). Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you have no need of `^` and `$` as **line**-boundaries, then these symbols act like `\A` and `\z` by default. Demo:

```js
let results = 
`a good test with
a second line, and ending with a bad z
a third line, and a bad z
a final line, and a good z`
.match(/^a (\w+)|(\w+) z$/g);

console.log(results);
```

If you **do** need to use line-boundary detection in your regex, then you would normally use the `/m` modifier, and then you can use your idea of look-around.

Alternatively, you could leave out the `/m` modifier, and just use `^`  and `$` for `\A` and `\z`, but then use look-around for detecting the line boundaries:

- start-of-line: `(?<![^\n\r])`
- end-of-line: `(?![^\n\r])`

```js
let results = 
`a bad test with
a good line, and ending with a good z
a third line, after a good line, and a bad z
a final line, and a bad z`
.match(/(?<![^\n\r]). good|good .(?![^\n\r])/g);

console.log(results);
```

For specific cases you can sometimes use other techniques. For instance, by default (so without `/s`) the pattern `.*` will capture anything until the end of the line, so you can be sure to be at a line-end after that capture.